# Using Verizon iPhone 5s internationally

Tags: sim, iphone

I have a Verizon iPhone 5s and live in the US. It's not unlocked/jail broken. I'm traveling to Scotland next week for 7 days.

How can I use my phone primarily for calling back to the US and within Scotland? I would like some data but don't need that much.

Can I buy a pre-paid SIM card once I arrive in Scotland and easily put that in my iPhone to use? I prefer not to add any services to my VZW account as it's so expensive and dealing with them is more trouble than it's worth.

I already know to turn off data roaming to avoid a surprise bill - anything else I should turn off while traveling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread from macosrumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1525435) (caveat emptor) at least as of the iPhone 5 it should be possible to use a Verizon iPhone in Scotland.